# Pyinstaller returns fatal error when clicking on the built exe

Tags: pandas, exe, pyinstaller, openpyxl, fatal-error

I've built a digital LogBook for the laboratory that I work in as a PhD in Physics, so it's tailored to our needs. The code runs fine using tkinter for GUI , pandas and openpyxl so that the inserted data can be stored to an excel file. The problem is that I need to turn it into an exe (and specifically an exe for 32-bit from a 64-bit machine). I've used for other apps I've built, the pyinstaller and they work great, but for this one nothing seems to work. I've been searching a week now for a possible solution but I cannot seem to find a way out. Not to mention that many of what I'm reading as answers to similar question is like Greek to me, since I'm a newbie in Python.  So, if there is anyone that can give me a clean-cut answer so that I can understand what I'm doing in the process, I would be grateful.

I'm working with Python 2.7.15 and Windows 10

Here are my imports:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from datetime import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import tkinter.ttk
```

Comment: could you supply us with the error that you are seeing? do you have a stack or error log you can include with your question?

Comment: It just says that it can't execute the script

Comment: It's always difficult to package Python libraries such as Pandas that have C extensions.